# LINEST function analogue for R

Tags: r, excel

I am new to R, and trying to use it. I need to get [LINEST](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/linest-HP005209155.aspx) function equivalent for R.

I can get lots of URL for least square from Google but I am not able to get one with constant values. I would like to use it for ANOVA.

For example, I want to use those arrays. first is y, and the others are dummy variables.

> y = c(42,37,41,39,43,41,37,40,39,38,41,32,28,34,32,30,33)
>
> x1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
>
> x2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
>
> x3 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)

If case of, LINEST, I can get the result by using `LINEST(Y1:YN,X11:X3N,TRUE)`.

P.S. in this case I should have the result as below:

In this case, I should have the result as below:

### | B      |   C  | const |

### | -9     |  -1  | 40.5  |

### | 1.16   | 1.22 | 0.82  |

### | 0.83   | 2.01 |   |

### | 33.74  | 14   |

### | 274.76 | 57   |

Comment: You should tell us here what the result is so we can be sure we are getting the right result in our answers. Although this is Excel we are talking about here, where computational results are rarely right in the first place.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I would like to, but I could not do that as I am not good at write markdown language.

Comment: Its only a few numbers from Excel surely? Copy the text in Excel, edit your question, paste in the text, select it, then hit the {} button to mark it as code. Like I just did for your data example.

Comment: Hey Spacedman! Sure the LINEST function only returns 12 values. I added. (with clumsy presentation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `summary(lm(y~x1+x2+x3))`, which should be easy to find out with Google if one knows that this is called "linear regression". However, you wouldn't even need to do the dummy encoding manually. Just use a `factor` variable and let R do it for you.

```
summary(lm(y~x1+x2+x3))

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
#
#Residuals:
#   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#  -3.5   -1.5    0.5    1.5    2.5 
#
#Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  31.5000     0.8238  38.240 1.45e-15 ***
#x1            9.0000     1.1650   7.726 2.05e-06 ***
#x2            7.5000     1.2218   6.138 2.57e-05 ***
#x3                NA         NA      NA       NA    
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
#Residual standard error: 2.018 on 14 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.8282,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.8036 
#F-statistic: 33.74 on 2 and 14 DF,  p-value: 4.419e-06
```

The `NA` values are there because we have an intercept in the model and the rank of the system is not sufficient to estimate four parameters. You could exclude the intercept using `summary(lm(y~x1+x2+x3-1))`, but it's not recommended.

Here is how to do this with a factor variable:

```
x <- factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3))
summary(lm(y~x))

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x)
#
#Residuals:
#   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#  -3.5   -1.5    0.5    1.5    2.5 
#
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  40.5000     0.8238  49.165  < 2e-16 ***
#x2           -1.5000     1.2218  -1.228     0.24    
#x3           -9.0000     1.1650  -7.726 2.05e-06 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 2.018 on 14 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.8282,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.8036 
#F-statistic: 33.74 on 2 and 14 DF,  p-value: 4.419e-06
```

Note how the intercept now is the mean for `x1` and the other coefficients compare to this mean.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to find. Thanks again Mr. Roland. Moreover, the way is much informative than one in Excel - p-value for example.